# Sticky Header and GridView with large amount of items rendering problems

Tags: flutter, flutter-gridview

On my Flutter app, I have this implementation of my layout

```
CustomScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController,
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        return myTopBannerWidget();
      } else {
        return StickyHeader(
          header: myTopStickyMenu(),
          content: myGridView(myList),
        );
      }
    }, childCount: 2)),
  ],
);

Widget myGridView(List<Object> list) {
    return GridView.builder(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
           mainAxisExtent: myExtent,
           crossAxisSpacing: 0,
           mainAxisSpacing: mySpacing,
           crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: myList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return MySingleWidget(list[index]);
        },
    );
}
```

Where on scroll, **myTopBannerWidget** disappear, **myTopStickyMenu** stay sticked on top, and **myGridView** content scroll.
The problem is that list passed to **myGridView** is very huge (around 2000 elements), and gridview build all **MySingleWidgets** before rendering it, slowing incredibly down the app. How i can tell gridview to build only visible items, and build the others when necessary (and keep stickyHeader behavior)?

Comment: "How i can tell gridview to build only visible items" - by removing `shrinkWrap: true` - I know you used it on purpose because otherwise you had other problems but .... actually you should use `SliverToBoxAdapter` and `SliverGrid.builder`

Comment: @pskink can you provide me a working example ? thank you.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/slivers-deep-dive-series-slivertoboxadapter-sliverlist-and-sliverfixedextentlist-80c2f1ad2f93

Answer (score 0):

think you are doing what you are asking to do!

builder named constructor main job is to build children (items) on demand, in which when the user scrolls it builds the next child.

`GridView.builder` constructor is appropriate for grid views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder **is called only for those children that are actually visible.**

hope that the slowness because of you are running in debug mode.

Comment: No, it doesn't :) i've put a print inside itemBuilder, and it's called for all items in list when gridview is created

Comment: @giozh , it shouldn't , there's something wrong with you. btw: myGridView's parameter List<Object> list is never used, you are using mylist instead.

Comment: it was a typo when i've paste the code